# Change the types in pandas DataFrame with special purpose?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a DataFrame with the type float

```
 Number
      2
    3.1
    4.3
```

I want to change it into a list:

```
 Number
    [2]
  [3.1]
  [4.3]
```

It can be easily be done like `list(str(x))`. However, because of my special using purpose, when I choose the list's element for each row such as `type(df.Number[0][0])`, it should be float not string (without using code to convert back into the float type)

Comment: Why...why do you want to do that? Putting non-scalar objects inside pandas/numpy containers is awful for performance.

Comment: `because of my special using purpose`. This needs expansion.

Comment: ok guys, https://plot.ly/python/bullet-charts/ I used this package to make chart. You guys can check `type(data.markers[4])` and `type(data.markers[4][0]` to see (first one is list, and second one is float). Don't know how they make the data like that with the original float dataset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `list comprehension`:

```
df['a'] = [[x] for x in df['a']]
print (df)
        a
0  [-1.0]
1   [0.5]
2   [5.0]
```

Comment: This is much better than mine below

Comment: @PraysonDaniel - Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why you would do that but this is how you can get what you want:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = [2,3.1,4.3]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['number'])

df['number'] = df['number'].apply(lambda x:np.array([x,]).tolist())

print(df['number'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are *adamant* you need this, extract a list from NumPy directly via [`np.ndarray.tolist`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html):

```
df['Number'] = df['Number'].values[:, None].tolist()

print(df)

  Number
0  [2.0]
1  [3.1]
2  [4.3]
```